# draw a quad in p5.js webgl 3d

Tags: javascript, p5.js

i want to draw a quad in p5.js with webgl support. My code is shown below

```
function setup() {
    myCanvas = createCanvas(window.innerWidth,500,WEBGL);
    myCanvas.parent('canvas');
}

function draw(){
    background(255);
    fill('blue');

    beginShape();

    vertex(-100,-100,20);
    vertex(100,-100,20);
    vertex(100,100,20);
    vertex(-100,100,20);


    endShape();

}
```

but i am gettig only a triangle. is there any other way to draw a quad in a 3d space in p5.js

Comment: Looks like this is still an open issue https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/1071

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote will always yield a triangle and not a quad/rect because you are starting from a point and ending at the same point by only covering 2 other points in between, i.e. you are having only 3 points (triangle).

For a quad (Square) you can make it as :

```
scale(70);
beginShape();
fill(1, 0, 0);
vertex(0, 0, 0);
vertex(0, 1, 0);
vertex(1, 1, 0);
vertex(1, 0, 0);
vertex(0, 0, 0);
endShape(CLOSE);
```

The code above has same starting point and ending point covering 3 distinct points in between making it total of 4 points. (A quad)

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
quad(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3,x4, y4).
```

Comment: And what do you do for the Z -axis?